# My XSLT 2.0 count() function not returning expected results

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a block of XML that looks like this:

```
    <wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Plan wd:Descriptor="Personal Floating Holiday">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9cae06e1e9c601054c26dc48e9790000</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Absence_Plan_ID">HCM_ABSENCE_PTO</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Off_Plan>
        <wd:Time_Off_Balance>66</wd:Time_Off_Balance>
       </wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group>
    
    <wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group>
        <wd:Time_Off_Plan wd:Descriptor="Personal Floating Holiday">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9cae06e1e9c601054c26dc48e9790000</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Absence_Plan_ID">HCM_ABSENCE_PTM</wd:ID>
        </wd:Time_Off_Plan>
        <wd:Time_Off_Balance>99</wd:Time_Off_Balance>
    </wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group>
```

I want to count the nodes and set a variable with the "correct" resulting number.

Here is what I tried.....

Here is my XSLT:

```
            <xsl:variable name="PTOTimeoffCount">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group/wd:Time_Off_Plan/wd:ID[@wd:type ='Absence_Plan_ID'] = 'HCM_ABSENCE_PTO')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
```

The resulting variable is '1' no matter if the nodes exist or not.  If there are no nodes, the variable is '1'.  If there are multiple nodes, the variable is '1'.  In the example XML above, I would expect '1' but there are times that there is not a matching node yet I still get '1' in the variable.  I suspect that I have my count() syntax wrong but I am pretty new to this and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an expression of the form `count(A = B)`. The value of `A = B` is always a boolean, true or false, and a boolean is a single item, therefore it is a sequence of length one.

You probably want something like `count(A[. = B])` instead.

Specifically, if `A` is an expression that selects a set of nodes, and you want to count how many nodes in `A` have the value `B`, then you need to select those nodes in `A` that have the value `B` (which you do using `A[. = B]`), and then apply `count()` to that selection.

Comment: Your suggestion did solve my problem but honestly, I am not sure why.  I think I mentioned that I am very new to xslt and am still learning.  Could you please explain the logic in your suggestion count(A[. = B])?

Comment: Well, when faced with code that doesn't make sense, you have to make a guess as to what was intended, so it's entirely possible that my guess was completely wrong. My guess was that you were trying to count how many elements in the selection `wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group/wd:Time_Off_Plan/wd:ID[@wd:type ='Absence_Plan_ID']` have the value 'HCM_ABSENCE_PTO', and that's achieved using `count(wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker_group/wd:Time_Off_Plan/wd:ID[@wd:type ='Absence_Plan_ID'][. = 'HCM_ABSENCE_PTO'])`.